# Getting batch predictions for TFrecords via CloudML

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, google-cloud-ml, tfrecord

I followed [this great tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census) and successfully trained a model (on CloudML). My code also makes predictions offline, but now I am trying to use Cloud ML to make predictions and have some problems.

To deploy my model I followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/deploying-models). Now I have a code that generates `TFRecords` via `apache_beam.io.WriteToTFRecord` and I want to make predictions for those `TFRecords`. To do so I am following [this article](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/batch-predict), my command looks like this:

```
gcloud ml-engine jobs submit prediction $JOB_ID --model $MODEL --input-paths gs://"$FILE_INPUT".gz --output-path gs://"$OUTPUT"/predictions --region us-west1 --data-format TF_RECORD_GZIP
```

But I get only errors:
`'Exception during running the graph: Expected serialized to be a scalar, got shape: [64]`

It seems like it expect data in a different format. I found the format specs for JSON [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/prediction-overview#online_prediction_input_data), but couldn't find how to do it with TFrecords.

UPDATE: here is the output of `saved_model_cli show --all --dir`

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['prediction']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['example_proto'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: unknown_rank
    name: input:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['probability'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (1, 1)
    name: probability:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['example_proto'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_STRING
    shape: unknown_rank
    name: input:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['probability'] tensor_info:
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    shape: (1, 1)
    name: probability:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Comment: Yuri, do you mind providing a bit more info? Can you provide the output of `saved_model_cli show --all --dir /path/to/model`? Also can you provide an ASCII version of one of the datapoints in your file?

Comment: @rhaertel80 Thank you for a quick respond! I added the output of `saved_model_cli`, but I am not sure how to provide you an ASCII version of one of the datapoints in my file. The file is a serialized TFRecord. Is there a tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you export your model, you need to make sure that it is "batchable", i.e., the outer dimension of the input Placeholder has `shape=[None]`, e.g.,

```
input = tf.Placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None])
...
```

That may require reworking the graph a bit. For instance, I see that the shape of your output is hard-coded to [1,1]. The outermost dimension should be `None`, this may happen automatically when you fix the placeholder, or it may require other changes.

Given that the name of the output is `probabilities`, I would also expect the innermost dimension to be >1, i.e. the number of classes being predicted, so something like `[None, NUM_CLASSES]`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! My code used `parse_single_example` - it was not doing the correct batching, so adding `shape=[None]` didn't work and I had to go through the code and replace `parse_single_example` via `parse_example`. Now it works

Comment: Happy to hear it!