# Exporting a Keras model as a TF Estimator: trained model cannot be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I encountered the following issue when trying to export a Keras model as a TensorFlow Estimator with the purpose of serving the model. Since the same problem also popped up [in an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54175038/creating-a-serving-graph-separately-from-training-in-tensorflow-for-google-cloud/54178060#54178060), I will illustrate what happens on a toy example and provide my workaround solution for documentation purposes. This behaviour occurs with Tensorflow 1.12.0 and Keras 2.2.4. This happens with actual Keras as well as with `tf.keras`.

The problem occurs when trying to export an Estimator that was created from a Keras model with `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator`. Upon calling `estimator.export_savedmodel`, either a `NotFoundError` or a `ValueError` is thrown.

The below code reproduces this for a toy example.

Create a Keras model and save it:

```
import keras
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1,
                                activation='sigmoid',
                                input_shape=(10, )))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd')
model.save('./model.h5')
```

Next, convert the model to an estimator with `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator`, add an input receiver function and export it in the `Savedmodel` format with `estimator.export_savedmodel`:

```
# Convert keras model to TF estimator
tf_files_path = './tf'
estimator =\
    tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model,
                                          model_dir=tf_files_path)
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    return tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(
        {model.input_names[0]: tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10])})

# Export the estimator
export_path = './export'
estimator.export_savedmodel(
    export_path,
    serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn())
```

This will throw:

```
ValueError: Couldn't find trained model at ./tf.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My workaround solution is as follows. Inspecting the `./tf` folder makes clear that the call to `model_to_estimator` stored the necessary files in a `keras` subfolder, while `export_model` expects those files to be in the `./tf` folder directly, as this is the path we specified for the `model_dir` argument:

```
$ tree ./tf
./tf
└── keras
    ├── checkpoint
    ├── keras_model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
    ├── keras_model.ckpt.index
    └── keras_model.ckpt.meta

1 directory, 4 files
```

The simple workaround is to move these files up one folder. This can be done with Python:

```
import os
import shutil
from pathlib import Path

def up_one_dir(path):
    """Move all files in path up one folder, and delete the empty folder
    """
    parent_dir = str(Path(path).parents[0])
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(path, f), parent_dir)
    shutil.rmtree(path)

up_one_dir('./tf/keras')
```

Which will make the `model_dir` directory look like this:

```
$ tree ./tf
./tf
├── checkpoint
├── keras_model.ckpt.data-00000-of-00001
├── keras_model.ckpt.index
└── keras_model.ckpt.meta

0 directories, 4 files
```

Doing this manipulation in between the `model_to_estimator` and the `export_savedmodel` calls allows to export the model as desired:

```
export_path = './export'
estimator.export_savedmodel(
    export_path,
    serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn())
```

> INFO:tensorflow:SavedModel written to:
>   ./export/temp-b'1549796240'/saved_model.pb