# Saving and doing Inference with Tensorflow BERT model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, bert-language-model

I have created a binary classifier with Tensorflow BERT language model. Here is the [link](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google-research/bert/blob/master/predicting_movie_reviews_with_bert_on_tf_hub.ipynb). After the model is trained, it saves the model and produces the following files. 
[image: pytho]

Prediction code.

```
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

#MODEL_FILE = 'graph.pbtxt'   


with tf.Session() as sess:   
  predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(f'/content/drive/My Drive/binary_class/bert/graph.pbtxt')
predictions = predict_fn(pred_sentences)
print(predictions)
```

Error

```
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /content/drive/My Drive/binary_class/bert/graph.pbtxt/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

After digging in this issue. I came across tf.train.Saver() class for saving the model. I changed the estimator train code to following to save the model. I referred this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model). I guess tensorflow estimators can be saved with it.

```
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  # Do some work with the model.
  saver = tf.train.Saver()
  estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=num_train_steps)  
  # Save the variables to disk.
  save_path = saver.save(sess, f'/content/drive/My Drive/binary_class/bert/tmp/model.ckpt')
```

And here is the error.

```
Beginning Training!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-0c9f9b70d76b> in <module>()
      9   sess.run(init_op)
     10   # Do some work with the model.
---> 11   saver = tf.train.Saver()
     12   estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=num_train_steps)
     13   # Save the variables to disk.

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py in _build(self, checkpoint_path, build_save, build_restore)
    860           return
    861         else:
--> 862           raise ValueError("No variables to save")
    863       self._is_empty = False
    864 

ValueError: No variables to save
```

The variables, weights are created in create_model function. What should I change to save my trained model?

Updates:
Code to save the model. I am not sure about the feature_spec and feature tensor.

```
feature_spec = {'x': tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string)}

def serving_input_receiver_fn():  

  serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string,
                                         shape=[1],  # batch size
                                         name='input_example_tensor')
  receiver_tensors = {'examples': serialized_tf_example}
  features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)

# Export the estimator
export_path = f'/content/drive/My Drive/binary_class/bert/'

estimator.export_saved_model(
    export_path,
    serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

I got this error :-

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-209298910d1e> in <module>()
     16 estimator.export_saved_model(
     17     export_path,
---> 18     serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in export_saved_model(self, export_dir_base, serving_input_receiver_fn, assets_extra, as_text, checkpoint_path, experimental_mode)
    730         as_text=as_text,
    731         checkpoint_path=checkpoint_path,
--> 732         strip_default_attrs=True)
    733 
    734   def experimental_export_all_saved_models(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in _export_all_saved_models(self, export_dir_base, input_receiver_fn_map, assets_extra, as_text, checkpoint_path, strip_default_attrs)
    854             builder, input_receiver_fn_map, checkpoint_path,
    855             save_variables, mode=ModeKeys.PREDICT,
--> 856             strip_default_attrs=strip_default_attrs)
    857         save_variables = False
    858 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in _add_meta_graph_for_mode(self, builder, input_receiver_fn_map, checkpoint_path, save_variables, mode, export_tags, check_variables, strip_default_attrs)
    927           labels=getattr(input_receiver, 'labels', None),
    928           mode=mode,
--> 929           config=self.config)
    930 
    931       export_outputs = export_lib.export_outputs_for_mode(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/estimator.py in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, config)
   1144 
   1145     logging.info('Calling model_fn.')
-> 1146     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
   1147     logging.info('Done calling model_fn.')
   1148 

<ipython-input-17-119a3167bf33> in model_fn(features, labels, mode, params)
      5     """The `model_fn` for TPUEstimator."""
      6 
----> 7     input_ids = features["input_ids"]
      8     input_mask = features["input_mask"]
      9     segment_ids = features["segment_ids"]

KeyError: 'input_ids'
```

Comment: Have you tried referring to the directory and not the file when loading your model ? Something like `predictor.from_saved_model(f'/content/drive/My Drive/binary_class/bert')`

Comment: I once had a similar issue (trained model could not be found) and documented it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54615708/exporting-a-keras-model-as-a-tf-estimator-trained-model-cannot-be-found).

Comment: @pLOPeGG Produces error
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: /content/drive/My Drive/binary_class/bert/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Answer (score 3):

The **create_model** function present in notebook takes some arguments. These features are passed to the model.

By updating the serving_input_fn function to following, the serving function works as expected.

Updated Code

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
  feature_spec = {
      "input_ids" : tf.FixedLenFeature([MAX_SEQ_LENGTH], tf.int64),
      "input_mask" : tf.FixedLenFeature([MAX_SEQ_LENGTH], tf.int64),
      "segment_ids" : tf.FixedLenFeature([MAX_SEQ_LENGTH], tf.int64),
      "label_ids" :  tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
  }
  serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string,
                                         shape=[None],
                                         name='input_example_tensor')
  print(serialized_tf_example.shape)
  receiver_tensors = {'example': serialized_tf_example}
  features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)

export_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/binary_class/bert/'
estimator._export_to_tpu = False  # this is important
estimator.export_saved_model(export_dir_base=export_path,serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

Comment: Can you add the code section for obtaining inference also from your saved model. It would be really helpful as lot of us are looking for one stop solution to this serving problem

Answer (score 1):

Using the `feature_spec` dict in the serving_input_receiver_fn did not work for me. I used the `serving_input_fn` below from [someone else asking the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61310331/performing-inference-with-a-bert-tf-1-x-saved-model/61788285#61788285).

To use the loaded estimator:

```
def serving_input_fn():
    label_ids = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None], name='label_ids')
    input_ids = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, MAX_SEQ_LEN], name='input_ids')
    input_mask = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, MAX_SEQ_LEN], name='input_mask')
    segment_ids = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, MAX_SEQ_LEN], name='segment_ids')
    input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn(
        {
        'label_ids': label_ids,
        'input_ids': input_ids,
        'input_mask': input_mask,
        'segment_ids': segment_ids
        }
    )()
    return input_fn


export_path = '../testing'
estimator._export_to_tpu = False  # this is important
estimator.export_saved_model(export_dir_base=export_path,serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_fn)

from tensorflow.contrib import predictor
predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model('../testing/1589420991')

def predict(sentences, predict_fn):
    labels = [0, 1]
    input_examples = [
        run_classifier.InputExample(
            guid="",
            text_a = x,
            text_b = None,
            label = 0
        ) for x in sentences] # here, "" is just a dummy label
    input_features = run_classifier.convert_examples_to_features(
        input_examples, labels, MAX_SEQ_LEN, tokenizer
    )

    all_input_ids = []
    all_input_mask = []
    all_segment_ids = []
    all_label_ids = []

    for feature in input_features:
        all_input_ids.append(feature.input_ids)
        all_input_mask.append(feature.input_mask)
        all_segment_ids.append(feature.segment_ids)
        all_label_ids.append(feature.label_id)
    pred_dict = {
        'input_ids': all_input_ids,
        'input_mask': all_input_mask,
        'segment_ids': all_segment_ids,
        'label_ids': all_label_ids
    }

    predictions = predict_fn(pred_dict)
    return [
        (sentence, prediction, label)
        for sentence, prediction, label in zip(pred_sentences, predictions['probabilities'], predictions['labels'])
    ]

pred_sentences = [
  "That movie was absolutely awful",
  "The acting was a bit lacking",
  "The film was creative and surprising",
  "Absolutely fantastic!",
]

predictions = predict(pred_sentences, predict_fn)
print(predictions)
[('That movie was absolutely awful',
  array([-0.26713806, -1.4505868 ], dtype=float32),
  0),
 ('The acting was a bit lacking',
  array([-0.23832974, -1.5508994 ], dtype=float32),
  0),
 ('The film was creative and surprising',
  array([-0.2784096, -1.4146391], dtype=float32),
  0),
 ('Absolutely fantastic!',
  array([-0.29031944, -1.3784236 ], dtype=float32),
  0),
 ('The patient has diabetes',
  array([-0.33836085, -1.2480571 ], dtype=float32),
  0),
 ('The patient does not have diabetes',
  array([-0.29378486, -1.3682064 ], dtype=float32),
  0)]
```