# Deploying Image Segmentation Model to Production using AI Platform: HTTP request 500 Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, artificial-intelligence, production-environment, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to deploy a tensorflow image segmentation model to production using the AI Platform of Google Cloud. I have previously succesfully deployed a custom image classification model using the AI platform yet when I try to deploy a custom segmentation model using:

`gcloud ai-platform predict --model=%MODEL_NAME% --json-instances="C:\Users\umara\Desktop\DLOCTseg\Normal Image.json" --verbosity debug`

I run into the following Error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.predict) HTTP request failed. Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

A little bit of googling around ([ML engine serving seems to not be working as intended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54287997/ml-engine-serving-seems-to-not-be-working-as-intended)) told me that the error could be due to the output size being too large. My output size is a 1 X 512 x 512 x 9 array for each image input.

The saved-model-cli

```
saved_model_cli show --all --dir C:\Users\umara\Desktop\DLOCTseg\export\v1
```

gives:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['bytes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: image_binary:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['conv2d_24'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 512, 512, 9)
        name: conv2d_24/Sigmoid:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

How can I deploy such a model on google cloud using AI platform? Is there a manual way to deploy my large output image segmentation model using Docker/ Kubernetes (is there a tutorial for this)? Any help regarding deploying this custom model on a server on Google Cloud and accessing prediction remotely would be appreciated. Thanks