# TensorFlow Serving for images as base64-encoded strings on Cloud ML Engine

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-estimator

### How to implement TensorFlow Serving Input function for images as base64-encoded strings and get prediction on Cloud ML Engine

I am planning to deploy the model on Cloud Machine Learning (ML) Engine after training it on-prem., but I have no idea how to implement the **serving input function**.

Additionally, I have tried to avoid TensorFlow low-level APIs and only focused on TensorFlow high-level APIs (**TensorFlow Estimator**). Below here in the blocks of code is the example code that I am working on.

---

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import datetime
import os

# create model
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.python.keras import models
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers

conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(150, 150, 3))

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
conv_base.trainable = False
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
              metrics=['acc'])

dt = datetime.datetime.now()
datetime_now = dt.strftime("%y%m%d_%H%M%S")
model_dir = 'models/imageclassifier_'+datetime_now
model_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), model_dir)
if not os.path.exists(model_dir):
    os.makedirs(model_dir)
print ("model_dir: ",model_dir)

est_imageclassifier = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model, model_dir=model_dir)

# input layer name
input_name = model.input_names[0]
input_name
```

This section is for image input function.

```
def imgs_input_fn(filenames, labels=None, perform_shuffle=False, repeat_count=1, batch_size=1):
    def _parse_function(filename, label):
        image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
        image = tf.image.decode_image(image_string, channels=3)
        image.set_shape([None, None, None])
        image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [150, 150])
        image = tf.subtract(image, 116.779) # Zero-center by mean pixel
        image.set_shape([150, 150, 3])
        image = tf.reverse(image, axis=[2]) # 'RGB'->'BGR'
        d = dict(zip([input_name], [image])), label
        return d
    if labels is None:
        labels = [0]*len(filenames)
    labels=np.array(labels)
    # Expand the shape of "labels" if necessary
    if len(labels.shape) == 1:
        labels = np.expand_dims(labels, axis=1)
    filenames = tf.constant(filenames)
    labels = tf.constant(labels)
    labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.float32)
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
    if perform_shuffle:
        # Randomizes input using a window of 256 elements (read into memory)
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=256)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(repeat_count)  # Repeats dataset this # times
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)  # Batch size to use
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    batch_features, batch_labels = iterator.get_next()
    return batch_features, batch_labels
```

I would like to create a **serving input function** that

1. **Get images as base64-encoded strings in JSON format**
2. **Convert them into Tensors and reduce the size to (?, 150, 150, 3) for prediction**

As shown below,

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():

''' CODE HERE!'''

return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(feature_placeholders, feature_placeholders)
```

To train and evaluate the model,

```
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=lambda: imgs_input_fn(train_files,
                                                                   labels=train_labels,
                                                                   perform_shuffle=True,
                                                                   repeat_count=1,
                                                                   batch_size=20), 
                                    max_steps=500)

exporter = tf.estimator.LatestExporter('Servo', serving_input_receiver_fn)

eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=lambda: imgs_input_fn(val_files,
                                                                 labels=val_labels,
                                                                 perform_shuffle=False,
                                                                 batch_size=1),
                                 exporters=exporter)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(est_imageclassifier, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

---

If I understand it correctly, the example of the input file to get the prediction on Cloud ML Engine should be something like

request.json

```
{"b64": "9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHJC...”}
{"b64": "9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0aHJC...”}
```

And

```
gcloud ml-engine predict --model MODEL_NAME  \
                --version MODEL_VERSION \
                --json-instances request.json
```

If you are reading until here and have some idea, could you please suggest me how to implement the serving input function for this particular case.

Many thanks in advance,

---

### 2nd Post - To update what I have done so far.

According to sdcbr's comment, below here is my serving_input_receiver_fn().

For _img_string_to_tensor() function or (prepare_image function), I guess that **I should do image preparation the same way as I trained the model** that you can see

imgs_input_fn() => _parse_function().

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    def _img_string_to_tensor(image_string):
        image = tf.image.decode_image(image_string, channels=3)
        image.set_shape([None, None, None])
        image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [150, 150])
        image = tf.subtract(image, 116.779) # Zero-center by mean pixel
        image.set_shape([150, 150, 3])
        image = tf.reverse(image, axis=[2]) # 'RGB'->'BGR'
        return image

    input_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None])

    images_tensor = tf.map_fn(_img_string_to_tensor, input_ph, back_prop=False, dtype=tf.float32)

    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver({model.input_names[0]: images_tensor}, {'image_bytes': input_ph})
```

After I trained the model and deployed the saved model on Cloud ML Engine. My input image was prepared into the format shown below.

```
{"image_bytes": {"b64": "YQ=="}}
```

But I found the error after getting a prediction via gcloud.

```
gcloud ml-engine predict --model model_1  \
               --version v1 \
               --json-instances request.json
```

> {   "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution:
>   AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\"assertion
>   failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP]\n\t
>   [[{{node
>   map/while/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_1/Assert}} =
>   Assert[T=[DT_STRING], summarize=3,
>   _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0\"](map/while/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/is_bmp,
>   map/while/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_1/Assert/data_0)]]\")"
>   }

**Did I do something wrong in _img_string_to_tensor function?**

and Could you please clarify me more about this tf.placeholder?

```
input_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None])
```

For your above code, you use shape=[1], but I think it should be shape=[None].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    def prepare_image(image_str_tensor):
        image = tf.image.decode_image(image_str_tensor,
                                     channels=3)
        image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [150, 150])
        return image

    # Ensure model is batchable
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303403/
    input_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None])
    images_tensor = tf.map_fn(
        prepare_image, input_ph, back_prop=False, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(
        {model.input_names[0]: images_tensor},
        {'image_bytes': input_ph})
```

You can add additional preprocessing in the `prepare_image` function. Note that `images_tensor` should get mapped on the name of the layer in your `tf.keras`model that is supposed to receive the input.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51432589/how-do-i-get-a-tensorflow-keras-model-that-takes-images-as-input-to-serve-predic) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49172710/what-does-google-cloud-ml-engine-do-when-a-json-request-contains-bytes-or-b6/49177909#49177909) related question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and suggestion. It meant a lot to me. However, I am **still stuck in this issue**. I have already posted below "2nd Post - To update what I have done so far."

Comment: I have just fixed this issue! Thank you so much again for your answer. It was right! My input Json was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

### Answer!

From sdcbr's comment, it is **the right answer** that I am looking for, but the problem that I just found out why it does not work.

Based on the error,

> {   "error": "Prediction failed: Error during model execution:
>   AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details=\"assertion
>   failed: [Unable to decode bytes as JPEG, PNG, GIF, or BMP]\n\t
>   [[{{node
>   map/while/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_1/Assert}} =
>   Assert[T=[DT_STRING], summarize=3,
>   _device=\"/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0\"](map/while/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/is_bmp,
>   map/while/decode_image/cond_jpeg/cond_png/cond_gif/Assert_1/Assert/data_0)]]\")"
>   }

It is because request.json was something like

```
{\"image_bytes\": {\"b64\": \"YQ==\"}}
{\"image_bytes\": {\"b64\": \"YQ==\"}}
.
.
```

That was supposed to be

```
{"image_bytes": {"b64": "YQ=="}}
{"image_bytes": {"b64": "YQ=="}}
.
.
```

After I cleaned up and removed all backslashes, **it works!**

*P.S. this is what you need to check it carefully. If you print it out on IPython notebook, it does not show backslashes. I have to open it on an editor and then I find the real problem.*

Comment: What's causing the \ slashes, and how do we avoid them in the first place instead of having to rectify the output?